# AVG function in SELECT affects the number of rows in query output

Tags: php, mysql, database

Below is my Query:

```
    $query = "
      SELECT *
      FROM Teacher t
      INNER JOIN Session s ON t.TeacherId = s.TeacherId
      JOIN Grade_Report gr ON s.SessionId = gr.SessionId
      WHERE
        ('".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."' = '' OR gr.SessionId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."') ";
```

The results are stored in a table which code looks like this:

```
<table border='1'>
      <tr>
      <th>Session ID</th>
      <th>Student Username</th>
      <th>Student Name</th>
      <th>Mark</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      </tr>
      <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "
      <tr>
      <td>{$row['SessionId']}</td>
      <td>{$row['StudentUsername']}</td>
      <td>{$row['StudentForename']} {$row['StudentSurname']}</td>
      <td>{$row['Mark']}</td>
      <td>{$row['Grade']}</td>
      </tr>";
        }
```

This query outputs 13 rows in the results which is fine when it selects all rows.

Now what happens is that I want the average mark for each session. So I include `'AVG(gr.Mark) as AvgMark'` in the query and include `<td>{$row['AvgMark']}</td>` in the table. The Calculation it outputs is correct The problem is that the query now only outputs 1 row which is the top row of the query result. I understand this as `AVG(gr.Mark)` only requires one row when outputted.

So my question is that except using `SELECT`'AVG(gr.Mark) as AvgMark' in the query to find average marks of each session, is there a way I can workout average of each mark outside the query by using php so that the query output shows the 13 rows and is not affected and I can store the calculation of the average below the table rather than in the table?

Comment: What result do you expect instead? What `average of each mark` means in case when you *don't have* `GROUP BY` clause at all?

Comment: what I mean is that I do not want to use SELECT clause to select average mark of each session (test). Can I create a function using php where it calculates average of each mark by retrieving $row['Mark'] and by using PHP's AVG to find the average and store it below the table, not in the table? I don't know how to use syntax in achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason AVG returns one row is that it's an aggregate function, and without a GROUP BY clause operates on all rows.

Averages in PHP are just like averages everywhere else; total your values and divide by the number of samples. Hence, you can easily calculate the average in code by changing the code to:

```
      <?php
        $total = 0;
        $count = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          $count++;
          $total += $row['Mark'];
          echo "
      <tr>
      <td>{$row['SessionId']}</td>
      <td>{$row['StudentUsername']}</td>
      <td>{$row['StudentForename']} {$row['StudentSurname']}</td>
      <td>{$row['Mark']}</td>
      <td>{$row['Grade']}</td>
      </tr>";
        }
$average = (int)($total/$count);
echo "<tr><td colspan=3></td><td>Average</td><td>$average</td></tr>".
```

Comment: It worked thank you, I now understand how to do total, count and average using php, cheers :)